# efficient way to double aggregation for a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate-functions

I have a questions regarding to aggregation a data frame double times, and involves re-formate the table.

I have a table, contains two columns: name, and category. The category is factor variable, contains 10 levels, say '0' to '9'. So the data frame looks like:

```
name   category
a        0
a        1
a        1
a        4
a        9
b        2
b        2
b        2
b        3
b        7
b        8
c        0
c        0
c        0
```

The result I want to aggregate looks like this:

```
name category.0  category.1  category.2 category.3 category.4 ..... category.9
a        1           2            0         0           1               1
b        0           0            3         1           0               0            
c        3           0            0         0           0               0
```

it counts how many '0','1',...,'9' for each unique name.

What I did to generate the result, is to use a simple aggregate function

```
new_df <- aggregate(category ~ name,df, FUN=summary)
```

and then unlist the second columns of new_df to get the result.

However, it is too slow. I would like to know if there is more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Are you, simply, looking for `table(df)`?

Comment: @alexis_laz, I don't understand what do you mean.  All names in the original df must be aggregated into one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dcast` from package `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2)

x = dcast(df, name~category)
setNames(x, c(names(x)[1], paste0('category',names(x)[-1])))

#  name category0 category1 category2 category3 category4 category7 category8 category9
#1    a         1         2         0         0         1         0         0         1
#2    b         0         0         3         1         0         1         1         0
#3    c         3         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the good answer. There is a mirror problem which I can not handle it. Assume there is no value for one category, (ex. category5 and category6 are missing in this case), I still want to keep the columns in the table. In my previous example, I can use set levels to force it. Is there a way in your answer? Thanks.

Comment: when I am trying to specify aggregation function, either table or summary, it reports: Error in dim(ordered) <- ns : 
  dims [product 4053480] do not match the length of object [129711360]